# WebSphere wsadmin jython - prompting for password

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I am looking for a way to prompt for password (that is, no input echo).
I am using jython in WebSphere's 7.0.0.19 wsadmin.

I've looked for it - it appears to be possible with import getpass or import termios (but I get "no module named ..." exception).

Any way to prompt for password anyway?

Thank you.

Comment: Was my answer useful? do you have any queries on that?

Comment: Even if this question is no longer needed for you still you need to check the answers provided and accept one if you feel it answers your question. Please do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code. It basically uses Java's console() if present (note that console [may not be present](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) all the time) else use raw_input() and password masking logic.

```
# if console is not available (ex: when invoked from a shell script or another java process)
# we need to fall back to use raw_input, but we should mask the password if we use it
import sys, thread, time, threading
from java.lang import String
def getPass(stream=None):
    console = java.lang.System.console()
    if console is None:
        global p_stopMasking
        if not stream:
            stream = sys.stderr
        try:
            p_stopMasking = 0
            threading.Thread(target=_doMasking,args=(stream,)).start()
            password = raw_input()
            p_stopMasking = 1
        except Exception, e:
            p_stopMasking = 1
            print "Error Occured"
            print e
            exit()
    else:
        password = console.readPassword()
    return String.valueOf(password)

def _doMasking(stream):
    while not p_stopMasking:
        stream.write("\010*")
        #stream.write("\n")
        stream.flush()
        time.sleep(0.01)

def populateCredentials():
    global username
    global password
    print 'Enter username:'
    username = raw_input();
    print 'Enter password:'
    password = getPass(sys.stdout);

# start main
print 'start program...'
p_stopMasking= 1
username     = None
password     = None
populateCredentials()
print 'username is : ' + username
print 'password is  : ' + password
```

Answer (score 1):

The following also worked for me:

```
raw_input("")
myPass = raw_input("Please enter a password: ")
```

This isn't perfect because it doesn't mask the password, but it does work. For some reason, if you don't specify the first "raw_input" invocation then the script won't block on the second one.